# Powershell Commands to a Computer that is only Reachable through RDP

Tags: windows, powershell, rdp

Is it possible to send Powershell commands to a computer that can only be reached by RDP? If yes, how?

Comment: you could, probably, force powershell to listen on 3389. https://serverfault.com/questions/384430/how-do-i-change-listener-port-in-powershell-winrm-2-0

Comment: Configure the winrm to listen port 3389 using the commands. Then you can do the remote operations.`Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\listener\*\Port 3389` or `winrm set winrm/config/Listener?Address=*+Transport=HTTP '@{Port="3389"}'`

Comment: How can you run two different applications using the same port?

Answer (score -1):

the help about_remoting topic covers various remote command options

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote

also to configure winRM for powershell you can open a local Powershell session and run the Following command **Enable-PSremoting**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/enable-psremoting

server 2012 and newer already have it enabled.